# Changing what is shown to a user using dynamic questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, logic

I want to, inside a webpage, as a user a series of questions, and then serve them up a page based on their response. But, I don't want to redirect them to a separate form/page.

For example:
1)Question: Do you want to see a Square?
2)Question: Do you want to see a Circle?
3)Question: Do you want it Red?
4)Question: Do you prefer Blue?
5)Question: Do you want it Orange?
6)Question: Do you prefer Yellow?

The user would see the first question, followed by a yes button and no button. If they clicked yes, then it would show them the 3rd question, if they clicked no, then it would show them the 2nd question. No to 3rd Question leads to 4th Q. No to 2nd Q leads to 5th Q, etc.
The end images are a Red Square, Blue Square, Orange Circle, Yellow Circle, and Black Square, and will be shown to users based on how they moved through the questions.

I know I can do this by giving an id to each question and set of buttons, and showing/hiding button/question sets using JS based on answers to other questions (then showing final based on last question answered) but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to do this, maybe with some sort of form, tree, and state assignment? In my real-world version it's possible that two answers lead to the same state.

Here's the beginning of my naive implementation:

```
<div id="b1">
<h5 id="q1">Question: Do you want to see a Square?</h5>
<button id="ay1">Yes</button><button id="an1">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b2"><h5 id="q2">Question: Do you want to see a Circle?</h5>
<button id="ay2">Yes</button><button id="an2">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b3"><h5 id="q3">Question: Do you want it Red?</h5>
<button id="ay3">Yes</button><button id="an3">No</button>
</div>
```

And a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s67zLzw/21/) of the idea

Comment: This seems like a simple decision tracking/logic flow question. Are you having a specific problem with the logic? Or are you looking for more of a code review? If the latter, you may want to redirect your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @TheJim01 my point is that as the number of options scales up, the HTML gets cumbersome and the whole setup is a bit ugly. Curious if there's a better way to do this with a single set of buttons, and some sort of state tracking or something.

Comment: My point is your question--as written--will attract opinion-based answers, because there are many ways to approach this problem. _Personally (already an opinion), I would create a single question element, replace its contents (the question) dynamically based on an array or structure of some sort, track the button click responses, then use the responses to formulate a result by creating DOM elements on-the-fly, or by importing an external HTML file_. But that's just one option, and that's the problem with your question--you'll get many valid options, but only one "accept."

Comment: I would counter that the nature of code is that there are many valid ways to do something, with various trade-offs and benefits. I think similar to asking a stack overflow question "how do I sort an array?" there are many answers. I know the naive solution, but also know there must be a better one, and I'm curious what some of the better ones are. I'll chose the "best" answer based on "best" code, which is definitely subjective (some combination of short and readable) but always has been on this website.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var shape, colour;
$("#an1").click(function() {
    $("#b1").fadeOut();
    $("#b2").fadeIn();
});
$("#ay1").click(function() {
    $("#b1").fadeOut();
    $("#b3").fadeIn();
    shape="Square";
});
$("#ay2").click(function() {
    $("#b2").fadeOut();
    $("#b3").fadeIn();
    shape="Circle";
});
$("#an2").click(function() {
    $("#b2").fadeOut();
    $("#b1").fadeIn();
});
$("#ay3").click(function() {
    $("#b3").hide();
    colour="red";
    show();
});
$("#an3").click(function() {
    $("#b3").fadeOut();
    $("#b4").fadeIn();
});
$("#ay4").click(function() {
    $("#b4").hide();
    colour="blue";
    show();
});
$("#an4").click(function() {
    $("#b4").fadeOut();
    $("#b5").fadeIn();
});
$("#ay5").click(function() {
    $("#b5").hide();
    colour="orange";
    show();
});
$("#an5").click(function() {
    $("#b5").fadeOut();
    $("#b6").fadeIn();
});
$("#ay6").click(function() {
    $("#b6").hide();
    colour="black";
    show();
});
$("#an6").click(function() {
    $("#b6").fadeOut();
    $("#b3").fadeIn();
});
function show() {
    var div="<div id='myShape' class='" + shape + "' style='background: " + colour + "'></div>";
    document.body.innerHTML+=(div);
}
```

```css
.box {
position: absolute;
}
#myShape {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: beige;
}
.Circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.Red {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class ="box" id="b1"><h5 id="q1">Question: Do you want to see a Square?</h5>
<button id="ay1">Yes</button><button id="an1">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b2" hidden><h5 id="q2">Question: Do you want to see a Circle?</h5>
<button id="ay2">Yes</button><button id="an2">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b3" hidden><h5 id="q3">Question: Do you want it Red?</h5>
<button id="ay3">Yes</button><button id="an3">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b4" hidden><h5 id="q4">Question: Do you want it Blue?</h5>
<button id="ay4">Yes</button><button id="an4">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b5" hidden><h5 id="q5">Question: Do you want it Orange?</h5>
<button id="ay5">Yes</button><button id="an5">No</button>
</div>
<div class ="box" id="b6" hidden><h5 id="q6">Question: Do you want it Black?</h5>
<button id="ay6">Yes</button><button id="an6">No</button>
</div>
```